# Why some strings are getting converted to numbers while others a not in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to java script. In console of web browser, I observed the below things.

```
"" - 1 + 0 = -1
"4" - 2 = 2
"4px" - 2 = NaN
" -9\n" - 5 = -14
```

I understood that strings will be converted to numbers while performing mathematical operations except addition. In 3rd operation, "4px" is not a valid number because of "px". So the result turned out to be NaN. But I didn't understand how " -9\n" is converted to -9 even though "\n' exists.

This might be a simple question. But I am unable to understand the reason. Can any one please let me know if I am missing any thing?

Comment: \n is the newline character, it's possible that it is being ignored or replaced by empty string when trying to convert.

Comment: `\n` is newline and considered as whitespace

Comment: whitespace characters are ignored when coercing to number, so characters like \t, \n, \r, space, etc won't cause a NaN value

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean all escape characters are converted to whitespace while doing mathematical operations in JavaScript?

Comment: They aren't converted when doing math operations. When js evaluates the string it changes the escape characters to their represented character. Meaning \t becomes the tab character \n newline etc. This all happens before the math op. Also it doesn't apply to all escape characters, ie \0 will cause a NaN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\n` is the escape sequence for the newline character. That's the one you get when you press the "Enter" key.

For example, there's a `\n` between the `cat` and the `dog` below.

```
cat
dog
```

If you do `"   9    " + 0` you will get `9` because JavaScript will ignore the surrounding spaces when converted to a number. The same occurs here because the newline is considered whitespace.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean all escape characters are converted to whitespace while doing mathematical operations in JavaScript?

Comment: @kadina Only ones which are whitespace characters. Escape sequences can include anything; even \\ (which is just a \ character). But `\t`, `\n`, `\r` all do.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you just happened across an escape character sequence that allows "-9\n" to be automatically converted to a Number. The character sequence "\n" represents a newline in most languages (Javascript included), and therefore treated like whitespace. This also means that that "\t" for tabs and "\r" for returns/newlines are similarly ignored.

```
> "-2\n" - 2
-4
> "-2\t" - 2
-4
> "-2\r" - 2
-4
```

But as soon as you test with a letter that isn't an escape sequence for whitespace (tabs, newlines, etc), or remove the escaping backslash, it's recognized as a letter and is evaluated to being NaN.

```
> "-2\a" - 2
NaN
> "-2n" - 2
NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

**The '\n' in a string is understood by many programming languages (if not all) as a new line character.**

What that means?
If you put a `\n` into your string like for example:

```
var fruits = "apple \nbanana \norange"
```

The final result printed by `console.log(fruits)` would look like this:

```
apple
banana
orange
```

You can find most escape sequences [on this article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) (do not worry about title it mostly works in other languages too)